# Bash help tallying/parsing substrings

Tags: arrays, string, bash, substring

I have a shell script I wrote a while back, that reads a word list (HITLIST), and recursively searches a directory for all occurrences of those words. Each line containing a "hit" is appended to file (HITOUTPUT).

I have used this script a couple of times over the last year or so, and have noticed that we often get hits from frequent offenders, and that it would be nice if we kept a count of each "super-string" that is triggered, and automatically remove repeat offenders.

For instance, if my word list contains "for" I might get a hundred hits or so for "foreign" or "form" or "force". Instead of validating each of these lines, it would be nice to simply wipe them all with one "yes/no" dialog per super-string.

I was thinking the best way to do this would be to start with a word from the hitlist, and record each unique occurrence of the super-string for that word (go until you are book-ended by why space) and go from there.

So on to the questions ...

1. What would be a good and efficient way to do this? My current idea
   was to read in the file as a string, perform my counts, remove
   repeat offenders from the the file input string, and output, but this is 
   proving to be a little more painful that I first suspected.
2. Would any specific data type/structure be preferred for this type of
   work?
3. I have also thought about building the super-string count as I
   create the HitOutput file, but I could not figure out a clean way of
   doing this either. Any thoughts or suggestions?

A sample of the file I am reading in, and my code for reading in and traversing the hitlist and creating the HitOutput file below:

```
# Loop through hitlist list

    while read -re hitlist || [[ -n "$hitlist" ]]
    do

        # If first character is "#" it's a comment, or line is blank, skip
        if [ "$(echo $hitlist | head -c 1)" != "#" ]; then

            if [ ! -z "$hitlist" -a "$histlist" != "" ]; then

                # Parse comma delimited hitlist
                IFS=',' read -ra categoryWords <<< "$hitlist"

                # Search for occurrences/hits for each hit
                for categoryWord in "${categoryWords[@]}"; do
                    # Append results to hit output string
                    eval 'find "$DIR" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -HniI "$categoryWord"' >> HITOUTPUT
                done

            fi
        fi
done < "$HITLIST"
```

> src/fakescript.sh:1:Never going to win the war you mother!
>
> src/open_source_licenses.txt:6147:May you share freely, never taking more than you give.
>
> src/open_source_licenses.txt:8764:May you share freely, never taking more than you give.
>
> src/open_source_licenses.txt:21711:No Third Party Beneficiaries. You agree that, except as otherwise expressly provided in this TOS, there shall be no third party beneficiaries to this Agreement. Waiver and Severability of Terms. The failure of UBM LLC to exercise or enforce any right or provision of the TOS shall
>   not constitute a waiver of such right or provision. If any provision of the TOS is found by a court of competent jurisdiction to be invalid, the parties nevertheless agree that the court should endeavor to give effect to the parties' intentions as reflected in the provision, and the other provisions of the TOS remain in full force and effect.
>
> src/fakescript.sh:1:Never going to win the war you mother!

An example of my hitlist file:

```
# Comment out any category word lines that you do not want processed (the comma delimited lines)
# -----------------

# MEH
never,going,to give,you up
# ----------------

# blah
word to,your,mother
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's divide this problem into two parts.  First, we will update the hitlist interactively as requires by your customer.  Second, we will find all matches to the updated hitlist.

#### 1. Updating the hitlist

This searches for all words in files under directory `dir` that contain any word on the hitlist:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -Erowhf <(sed -E 's/.*/([[:alpha:]]+&[[:alpha:]]*|[[:alpha:]]*&[[:alpha:]]+)/' hitlist) dir |
    sort |
    uniq -c |
    while read n word
    do
       read -u 2 -p "$word occurs $n times.  Include (y/n)? " a
       [ "$a" = y ] && echo "$word" >>hitlist
    done
```

This script runs interactively.  As an example, suppose that `dir` contains these two files:

```
$ cat dir/file1.txt 
for all  foreign or catapult also cat.
The catapult hit the catermaran.
The form of a foreign formula
$ cat dir/file2.txt 
dog and cat and formula, formula, formula
```

And `hitlist` contains two words:

```
$ cat hitlist
for
cat
```

If we then run our script, it looks like:

```
$ bash script.sh
catapult occurs 2 times.  Include (y/n)? y
catermaran occurs 1 times.  Include (y/n)? n
foreign occurs 2 times.  Include (y/n)? y
form occurs 1 times.  Include (y/n)? n
formula occurs 4 times.  Include (y/n)? n
```

After the script is run, the file hitlist is updated with all the words that you want to include.  We are now ready to proceed to the next step:

#### 2. Finding matches to the updated hitlist

To read each word from a "hitlist" and search recursively for matches while ignoring, `foreign` even if the hitlist contains `for`, try:

```
grep -wrFf ../hitlist dir
```

`-w` tells grep to look only for full-words.  Thus `foreign` will be ignored.

`-r` tells grep to search recursively.

`-F` tells grep to treat the hitlist as word, not regular expressions. (optional)

`-f ../hitlist` tells grep to read words from the file `../hitlist`.

Following on with the example above, we would have:

```
$ grep -wrFf ./hitlist dir
dir/file2.txt:dog and cat and formula, formula, formula
dir/file1.txt:for all  foreign or catapult also cat.
dir/file1.txt:The catapult hit the catermaran.
dir/file1.txt:The form of a foreign formula
```

If we don't want the file names displayed, use the `-h` option:

```
$ grep -hwrFf ./hitlist dir
dog and cat and formula, formula, formula
for all  foreign or catapult also cat.
The catapult hit the catermaran.
The form of a foreign formula
```

#### Automatic update for counts 10 or less

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -Erowhf <(sed -E 's/.*/([[:alpha:]]+&[[:alpha:]]*|[[:alpha:]]*&[[:alpha:]]+)/' hitlist) dir |
    sort |
    uniq -c |
    while read n word
    do 
       a=y
       [ "$n" -gt 10 ] && read -u 2 -p "$word occurs $n times.  Include (y/n)? " a
       [ "$a" = y ] && echo "$word" >>hitlist
    done
```

#### Reformatting the customer's hitlist

I see that your customer's hitlist has extra formatting, including comments, empty lines, and duplicated words.  For example:

```
$ cat hitlist.source
# MEH
never,going,to give,you up
# ----------------

# blah
word to,your,mother
```

To convert that to format useful here, try:

```
$ sed -E 's/#.*//; s/[[:space:],]+/\n/g; s/\n\n+/\n/g; /^$/d' hitlist.source | grep . | sort -u >hitlist
$ cat hitlist
give
going
mother
never
to
up
word
you
your
```

Comment: I get all of that, the problem I have is how best to count and remove repeat superstring offenders. If I "foreign" is returned 50 times from hitting "for", and perhaps "form" is returned 25 times, I would like some sort of dialog like the following:

The string " foreign " was returned 50 times due to hitting "for". Would you like to remove all of them? yes/no

The string " form " was returned 25 times due to hitting "for". Would you like to remove all of them? yes/no

Comment: _"If I 'foreign' is returned 50 times from hitting 'for':_ What I showed in the example is that, __with this code__, that does __not__ happen.

Comment: I understand, but that's not the behavior I am looking for.

Comment: But I do think I can use some of that to speed things up.

Comment: Suppose you had `for` and `form` in your hitlist.  Would you want `formula` to appear as a superstring of `for` or `form` or both?

Comment: Both in this case

Comment: we have a HARD requirement by our customer to actually have personal review of word hits (thus not able to use smarter grep flags). We do have permission to eliminate recurring (more than say 10 times) hits on a word with a single yes/no dialog (thus still satisfying the personal review requirement). So ideally, if "for" was on the hitlist, we would get some sort of dialog that says "The word "form" occurred 25 times, would you like to remove those lines from the report?: yes/no"

Comment: Are the hitlist words, as in the examples, all prefixes?  In other words, if `for` is in the hitlist should it match both `form` and `before`?

Comment: Also, how large (`du -shc directory/`) is the body of text?

Comment: The hitlist consists of words (can even be a string), so essentially if the word or string is matched anywhere, prefix, full word, end of a word, whatever, then the line is sent out for personal review.

The body of text can consist of tens of thousands of lines (thus the need to speed up the process)

Comment: OK.  I updated the answer to add an interactive script.

Comment: I think I can use a lot of that. The two exceptions, 1)I need to include everything by default, and exclude items from the list if instructed, and 2)I only want a dialog for hits with a count > 10, everything else is reviewed.

Comment: I just ran it, and I can certainly use a lot of this. The hitlist.txt file isn't built interactively, it is given to us by our customer. The file/log output which requires personal review is built interactively though. So I need to read in the hitlist, then for each word in hitlist, search recursively through directory for that word, store all of this into some sort of temporary data structure, offer up the dialogs and then generate output from that. I think I have enough now to go by though.

Comment: Yes, do make a copy of hitlist before running this script.   It is not clear to me how the rest of it differs from what you need but, if it has given you enough to work with, then I guess that's good.

Comment: Basically I cannot change the hitlist I am grepping for, I can change the output that will be reviewed by people. So I recursively grep a directory for each word in the hitlist, and generate a file containing the lines that returned by that grep. Many of the strings that are returned are common "something something formula something something" when the hitlist word is "for" so I am provided the user the option to wipe all of those out at once, instead of reading/validating each line with a hit of "formula"

Comment: _"I cannot change the hitlist"_   So, make a copy of it and use my code on the copy.  If that is not acceptable, I don't get what the problem is.  _"wipe all of those out at once, instead of reading/validating each line with a hit of `formula`"_  Yes, that is what my code does.  It counts up the occurrences of `formula` and, if it is over 10, asks you just once whether you want to keep or remove all occurrences of `formula`.

Comment: Ah I see what the confusion is. When I ran your code it recursively grabbed every single word in a directory and asked me if I wanted that word to be in the list. My test directory had an open source license so I literally had thousands of yes/no dialogs

Comment: I was able to make it work thank you. I am guessing the problem was some sort of match all wildcard issue with my hitlist file shown above.

Comment: @user1524459 Very good.  My code assumed that `hitlist` was a list of words, one word per line, with no additional formatting or complications.

Comment: @user1524459 I just added code to convert your customer's hitlist to one that is useful here.

Comment: @user1524459 Just to be clear, after processing, the `hitlist` file should  have __no__ blank lines because `grep` would interpret a blank line as matching __everything__.  (I suspect that that is the behavior you reported earlier.)